# Can anyone tell me how to run this command in javacode?

Tags: java, command-line

I need to run following command in JavaCode:

```
cd /Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-api/../ngcsc-poc-impala; mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample -Dexec.arguments='query.txt'
```

This command is good if I run in shell, but I need to run it in java code directly, so I used this one:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd = "cd "+gotoPath+"; mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample -Dexec.arguments='query.txt'";
System.out.print(cmd);
rt.exec(cmd);
```

But After I am checking result, it is not running and there is no file generated, so it seemed the cmd is not running successfuly.

What's wrong here?
Thanks

I will try that solution to see the result, furthermore, I tried this:

```
String[] cmds = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-impala && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample -Dexec.arguments='query.txt'" };
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds);
```

Why this one is also not working? Any idea?
Thanks

Hi @MadProgrammer, I am using your solution as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "/usr/local/bin/mvn",
                "exec:java",
                "-Dexec.mainClass=com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample",
                "-Dexec.arguments='/Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-impala/query.txt'"
        );
        pb.directory(new File("/Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-api/../ngcsc-poc-impala"));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            try (InputStream is = p.getInputStream()) {
                int in = -1;
                while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char)in);
                }
            }
            int exitCode = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nProcess exited with " + exitCode);
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I am getting error as follows:

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: '/Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-impala/query.txt' (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample.main(ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample.java:51)
```

It doesn't make sense to me, the file is there, why the process can not find it?
Thanks

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder` which will allow you to specify the working directory

Comment: Or write a batch script and then invoke that from Java.

Comment: A key takeaway is that `;` delimits a whole command; bash lets you run multiple commands on the same line for convenience, but really you're running multiple, separate commands.  As such, when executing commands from a process library you need to execute each command individually, rather than something like `rt.exec("command1; command2")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by trying `ProcessBuilder`, it is far more configurable then `Runtime.exec`, apart from allowing to redirect the error stream into the input stream (making it easier to read), you can specify the working directory that the command should be executed from within.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                "mvn",
                "exec:java",
                "-Dexec.mainClass=com.cloudera.example.ClouderaImpalaJdbcExample",
                "-Dexec.arguments='query.txt'"
);
pb.directory(new File("/Users/frankhe/projects/poc_demo/ngcsc-poc-api/../ngcsc-poc-impala"));
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    try (InputStream is = p.getInputStream()) {
        int in = -1;
        while ((in = is.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)in);
        }
    }
    int exitCode = p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("\nProcess exited with " + exitCode);
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```